# Angular filter for html code

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a case where I calculate by date if less or more than 72 hours depending on the case, show me a red square or a green. The fact is that I want to see only filtered by red or green only and  I don't know how i can do it.

```
var app = angular.module('MainApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute', 'xeditable', ]);


app.controller('dashboardController', function ($scope, $http, $modal, $sce, myfactory, allPhoneModelsFactory, allInventoryFactory) {


    $scope.objects = [];
    $scope.grupos = [];
    $scope.longitud = [];
    $scope.eventos = [];
    $scope.modelos = [];

    //Funci?n que devuelve las instalaciones de un usuario
    $http.get(myfactory.URLOperation)
            .success(function (data) {
                var groups = data;
                angular.forEach(groups, function (group) {
                    var group2 = group;
                    angular.forEach(group2.sites, function (oneSite) {
                        oneSite.phoneDescription = $scope.getPhoneDescription(oneSite.phonedesc);
                        $scope.longitud.push(oneSite);
                        $scope.objects.push(oneSite);
                        $scope.predicate = 'msisdn';
                        $scope.reverse = true;
                        $scope.order = function (predicate) {
                            $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
                            $scope.predicate = predicate;
                        };
                    })
                });
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                window.alert('Something Wrong...');
            });

    $scope.getHour = function (input) {
        var datos = input;
        input.forEach(function (data) {
            var date1 = new Date();
            var date2 = new Date(data.LastHWEvent);
            var date3 = new Date(data.LastTestEvent)
            var timeDiff = Math.abs((date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var timeDiff2 = Math.abs((date1.getTime() - date3.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            if (timeDiff <= 72 || timeDiff2 <= 72) {
                $scope.html1 = '<span class="fa fa-square fa-2x"style="color:#336600"></span>';
                data.trustedHtmlgreen = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html1);
            }
            else {
                $scope.html2 = '<span class="fa fa-square fa-2x"style="color:red"></span>';
                data.trustedHtmlred = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html2);
            }
        })
    }






});
```

For that i use the getHour function.

```
         <table id="tableinventario" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive dataTable no-footer" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
                                <tr role = "row" class="info text-center">
                                    <th ng-click="order('msisdn')">Número Teléfono <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('icc')">ICC <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>

                                    <!--th>IMEI</th-->
                                    <th ng-click="order('ActivationStatus')">Activación <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                                    <th >EN-8128 </th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('sitename')" >Instalación <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('siteaddress')">Dirección <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('sitecity')">Ciudad <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
                                    <th ng-click="order('sitezip')">Código Postal <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>

                                    <th ng-click="order('phonedesc')">Modelo Teléfono <i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>

                                </tr>


                                <tr class=" text-center" ng-repeat-start="object in filteredsites = (objects | filter:searchText | filter:{parentgroupid:selectedgroup||undefined}) | filter:tableFilter| orderBy:predicate:reverse" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails" >
                                    <td editable-text="object.msisdn" onaftersave="updateUser(object)">{{object.msisdn}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.icc}}</td>

                                    <!--td>{{object.ActivationStatus}}</td-->
                                    <td><span ng-init="countestatus(filteredsites)"  ng-show="object.ActivationStatus=='AC' && object.ContractingMode=='0'" class="fa fa-square fa-2x"style="color:#336600"></span><span ng-show="object.ContractingMode=='2' && object.ActivationStatus=='AC'  "  ><img src="../img/Vodafone_logo.png" width="25" height="25" style="background-color: #336600 ;border-radius: 5px"></span><span ng-show="object.ActivationStatus=='PA'"  class="fa fa-square fa-2x"style="color:#FFCC33"></span><span ng-show="object.ActivationStatus=='DE'" class="fa fa-square fa-2x"style="color:#CC0000"></span></td>
                                    <td ng-init="getHour(filteredsites)"  ng-bind-html="object.trustedHtmlgreen || object.trustedHtmlred"  ></td>

                                    <td  editable-text="object.sitename" ng-model="editobject.name" onaftersave="updateUser(object)">{{object.sitename}}</td>
                                    <td editable-text="object.siteaddress" ng-model="editobject.siteaddress" onaftersave="updateUser(object)" >{{object.siteaddress }}</td>
                                    <td editable-text="object.sitecity" ng-model="editobject.sitecity" onaftersave="updateUser(object)">{{object.sitecity}}</td>
                                    <td editable-text="object.sitezip" ng-model="editobject.sitezip" onaftersave="updateUser(object)">{{object.sitezip}}</td>
                                    <td>{{object.phoneDescription}}</td>

                                </tr>

                                <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="showDetails"> 

                                    <td colspan="1"></td>


                                    <td colspan="7">

                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

                                    <!--<tr><td>Teléfono</td><td> {{object.msisdn}}</td><th>ID instalación</th><td> {{object.liftsiteid}}</td><th>Modelo teléfono</th><td> {{object.liftsiteid}}</td></tr>-->
                                            <!--<tr ><th>ICC</th><td> {{object.icc}}</td><th>Dirección</th><td> {{object.siteaddress}}</td><th>PIN1</th><td> {{object.pin1}}</td></tr>-->
                                            <tr ><th>IMEI</th><td> {{object.imei}}</td><th>PIN1</th><td editable-text="object.pin1" > {{object.pin1}}</td></tr>
                                            <tr ><th>RAE1</th><td editable-text="object.rae1" > {{object.rae1}}</td><th>PIN2</th><td editable-text="object.pin2"> {{object.pin2}}</td></tr>
                                            <tr ><th>RAE2</th><td editable-text="object.rae2" > {{object.rae2}}</td><td colspan="2"><button class="btn btn-outline btn-default" ng-click="open(object)" >Eventos</button></td></tr>
                                            <tr><th>Comentarios</th><td colspan="1" editable-text="object.comments" > {{object.comments}}</td><td colspan="2"><button class="btn btn-outline btn-default" ng-click="updateUser(object.liftsiteid)" >Guardar Cambios</button></td></tr>

                                   </table></td>
                                </form>

<!--                                <td colspan="2"> <a> Teléfono</a> <div>{{object.msisdn}}</div><a>ICC:</a> <div> {{object.icc}}</div> <div><a> IMEI</a> {{object.imei}}</div> <div><a> Último Evento HW</a> {{object.LastHWEvent | date:'MM-dd-yyyy HH:MM:ss'}}</div></td>
                                    <td colspan="3"> <a> ID Instalación</a> <div>{{object.liftsiteid}}</div><a>Dirección:</a> <div> {{object.siteaddress}}</div> <div><a> Código Postal</a> {{object.sitezip}}</div> <div><a> Ciudad</a> {{object.sitecity}}</div></td>

                                    <td colspan="2"> <a>Modelo Teléfono</a><div></div><a>Comentarios:</a> <div> {{object.comments}}</div> </td>
                                    <td colspan="2"> <div><a> Rae1: </a> {{object.rae1}}</div>  <div><a> Rae2: </a> {{object.rae2}}</div> <a>Pin1:</a> <div> {{object.pin1}}</div> <div><a> Pin2: </a> {{object.pin2}}</div></td>

                                    <td colspan="1"> <div> <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="open(object)">Eventos</button></div>  </td>-->
                                    <div >



                                    </div>
                                </tr>




                            </table>
```

Comment: presented code is badly formatted, contains commented out code which is obviously irrelevant and in current formulation it is not clear do you wish to get extra styling based on date or you wish to filter out items in a list based on item date

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple filter check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ADnAQpR22Asfo7yyaOJj)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.date= "15.07.2015 10:00"
});
app.filter('passed', function() {
    return function (input) {
        if (input == null || input == "") {
             return "";
        }
        var past = new Date(input).getTime();
        var h72 = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 72; 
        var pastClass = (new Date().getTime() - past < h72) ? "red":"green";
        return pastClass;
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<p ng-class=" date | passed "> hello</p>
<input ng-model="date"/>
```